# Add custom text in taskbar programmatically

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi, .net-core

[image]

I want to display custom text in windows taskbar, like displayed in image [Data: xxxxxx]

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2219/Extending-Explorer-with-Band-Objects-using-NET-and

Comment: @tom Neither `IDeskBand` nor `IDeskBand2` are supported as of Windows 7.

Comment: @tom *We should use [thumbnail toolbars](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/shell/taskbar-extensions#thumbnail-toolbars) in new development in place of desk bands, which are not supported as of Windows 7.*